# React-Native & Expo: Back navigation between Drawer and Bottom-Tab with multiple stacks as Bottom-Tab screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nested, navigation, expo

Given N stacks (@react-navigation/stack) in the bottom-tab navigator (@react-navigation/bottom-tabs), and M screens in the drawer navigator (@react-navigation/drawer), following a structure similar like this one:

**Bottom-tab navigator**

- Stack-A (main screen: A, other screens: G, H)
- Stack-B (main screen: B)
- Stack-C (main screen: C)

**Drawer navigator**

- Screen-D
- Screen-E
- Screen-F

I want to be able to open the drawer in any bottom-tab selected stack (A, B or C) and navigate to any screen (D, E or F).
**With a drawer screen (D, E or F) opened, I want to be able to go back to the bottom-tab selected stack in which the drawer was opened by clicking in the headerBackImage, a property of Stack Navigator.**

**Practical example**: Stack-A (with screen G selected) -> Drawer -> Screen-D

**Desired outcome**: In this case, I would like to have a goBack function in Screen-D, that takes action by clicking on the left button on the stack header, to go back to the screen G.

I have tried different nested-stack implementations (Drawer inside the each Stack, Bottom-Tab in Drawer, ...) without any sucess.

Could some one help me please? Thanks in advance.